# How can I use the same / existing external terminal (session) when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Every time I debug (using an external Terminal) it opens a new session.

- Is it possible to reuse the same window / session?
- Or if not to close the current one so it doesn't keep opening a new window?

Similar questions are related to the internal Terminal.
I'm using iTerm2 on macOS.

Here's my launch.json config:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (External)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "python": "/Users/josip/.virtualenvs/myproject-JnedzVU7/bin/python",
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            // "justMyCode": false,
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"

        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem only exists with iTerm, as everything works as expected with Terminal and the existing session is used for successive run/debug executions.

The difference in behaviour is due to the way the applescripts that send the debugging command to the external terminal are written. The [script for Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/externalTerminal/node/TerminalHelper.scpt) ([readable gist](https://gist.github.com/willdhorn/bd1e15ec1e20b25659b7a63f43c32837)) contains logic for finding available session and telling the app to run the command with that session. Conversely, the [script for iTerm](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/externalTerminal/node/iTermHelper.scpt) ([readable gist](https://gist.github.com/willdhorn/944e729b802a5e3007d1261336cfd929)) is about as simple as can be for sending commands to run in iTerm.

While the Terminal script has functions for determining the right session and window to use, the iTerm script has only the following (excl. validation steps which are identical):

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    set new_term to (create window with default profile)
    delay 1
    tell new_term
        tell the current session
            write text cmd
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

[This is where the script is loaded and used to run the command in the configured terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/bb7d9597f5def37f629cb8cb498da75c399c8e2f/src/vs/platform/externalTerminal/node/externalTerminalService.ts#L136)

I've scanned the [iTerm scripting documentation](https://iterm2.com/3.0/documentation-scripting.html) and it should be possible to replicate the Terminal behaviour using the iTerm APIs if you want to make a feature request or submit a pull request with the change.